# Buttons that display two images side by side when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

Im very new to HTML and javascript. I need help with a javascript and HTML function. I need to create a basic page with 6 buttons. Each button when clicked displays two images within the browser. The code below I have the layout however I cannot figure out the javascript function to display the images when clicked. The two images below are the type of images I'm trying to display. And the code for the buttons gives an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<img src="http://131940.qld.gov.au//DMR.Controls/WebCams/DisplayImage.ashx?FilePath=\Metropolitan\MRMETRO-1458.jpg&amp;-1918551107" id="page_0_content_2_imgWC" class="cam" alt="">
<a href="http://imgur.com/GnzZKDA"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GnzZKDA.png" title="" /></a>

</center>

<center>
<body>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera One</button>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera Two</button>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera Three</button>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera Four</button>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera Five</button>
<button onclick="display images "http.example.jpg" + "http.example2.jpg">Camera Six</button>
</body>
</center>
```

This is just an example. I know I need to create a function for the onclick event that will display two different images for each button. This is what I need help with.

Even if there is an onclick event that is global that is used to display images would be great.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have this code to do what I wish with one image...How can I get two images into the code???/?

```
<style type="text/css"> 
img{width:300px;height:250px;border:0;} 
.show{display:block;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function showImg()
{
   var obj=document.getElementById('image01');
   obj.className = 'show';
}
</script>
</head> 

<html> 
<body> 

<img id="image01" src="http://i.imgur.com/GnzZKDA.png" class="hide"> 
<br/> 
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "Show image"> 
</html>
```

Comment: How many images in total? There are six buttons, so would that be 12 images?

Comment: Yes thats correct. Each button would display two different images. So 12.

Comment: If the images are static (i.e. there are always the same 12 images), you can simply add more `img` elements with `id="image01"`, `id="image02"` etc, and hide or show any two of them with the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgs = [
 // do not change this...... arrays index start at 0.. 
  [], 
  // write your img url below... like this...
["http://i.imgur.com/GnzZKDA.png" , "http://i.imgur.com/GnzZKDA.png" ],
 ["" , "" ],
  ["" , "" ],
  ["" , "" ],
  ["" , "" ],
  ["" , "" ]
  ];

function showImg (imgIndex) {
  document.getElementById('img1').src = imgs[imgIndex][0] ;
  document.getElementById('img2').src = imgs[imgIndex][1] ;
  }
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
img{width:300px;height:250px;border:0;} 

</style>

<img id="img1" src="" >
  <img id="img2" src=""  >

<br>

<input type="button" value="Camera One" onclick="showImg(1)" >
  <input type="button" value="Camera Two" onclick="showImg(2)" >
  <input type="button" value="Camera Three" onclick="showImg(3)" >
  <input type="button" value="Camera Four" onclick="showImg(4)" >
  <input type="button" value="Camera Five" onclick="showImg(5)" >
  <input type="button" value="Camera Six" onclick="showImg(6)" >
```

Comment: Psych Half this works perfectly. You're a genius. I'd seen image arrays in other examples but had never thought to use it. Thank you.

Comment: "Psych Half... You're a genius." funny statement. hehe anyways.. thanks, and i'm happy i could help you.. umm.. learning html, css and javascript can be pretty hard at beginning.. but once you start coding.. you'll get the hang of it.. there are more better ways to make an image array..n you will eventually know that.. try your best to learn new things and if you get stuck.. you can always ask me or here ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            var rel=$("#bigImg").attr('rel');

            var actualrel=parseInt (rel);
            if (actualrel<4) {
                bigImg=actualrel+1;
                }
                else{
                    bigImg=1;   
            }
            $("#bigImg").attr("rel",bigImg);

            rel="#"+rel;
            var src1=$(rel).attr("src");
            $("#bigImg").attr("src",src1);
        });
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            var rel=$("#bigImg").attr('rel');
            var actualrel= parseInt(rel)
            if (actualrel<4){
                bigImg=5-actualrel;
            }
            else{
                bigImg=1;
            }
            $("#bigImg").attr("rel",bigImg);

            rel="#"+rel;

            var src1=$(rel).attr("src");
            $("#bigImg").attr("src",src1);
        });
    });


</script>
```